# I want to change URL for specific page for my wordpress site through htaccess or using wordpress function

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have URL like this
http://www.shreyinnovations.com/edudemo/app-detail/?app-detail=A-Level%20Revision
which I need to replace like below
http://www.shreyinnovations.com/edudemo/app/A-Level%20Revision

I change my .htaccess file to change like below

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /edudemo/
RewriteRule ^app/([0-9]+)$ app-detail?app-detail=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /edudemo/index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I also used wordpress function to change appche rule for rewrite address like this

```
add_action( 'init', 'app_detail_rewrite_rules' );

add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'app_detail_rewrite_rules' );
function app_detail_rewrite_rules(){
   add_rewrite_rule('^app/([0-9]+)','app-detail?app-detail=$matches[1]','top');
}
```

but still I can't get url what I want.please let me know if anyone have solution for this.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this code before the WP rule-set:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/edudemo/app-detail [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  app-detail=([^&/]+) [NC]
RewriteRule .*               /edudemo/app/%1?    [R=301,L]              

# BEGIN WordPress
```

For internal mapping, remove R=301 from [R=301,L]